# 'Java gateway process exited before sending its port number' Spark

Tags: python, java, apache-spark, pyspark, terminal

```
ingodavila@Ingos-MacBook-Pro ~ % pyspark        
Python 3.8.5 (v3.8.5:580fbb018f, Jul 20 2020, 12:11:27) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
21/10/19 17:33:55 WARN Utils: Your hostname, Ingos-MacBook-Pro.local resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using 10.106.3.34 instead (on interface en0)
21/10/19 17:33:55 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
21/10/19 17:33:55 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.1.2
      /_/

Using Python version 3.8.5 (v3.8.5:580fbb018f, Jul 20 2020 12:11:27)
Spark context Web UI available at http://10.106.3.34:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1634636037378).
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>> quit()
```

Everything works fine here but when I try:

```
pyspark --master yarn --num-executors 3
```

I get this error:

```
Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

I already installed Java 8 installed.

Comment: The problem seems to be because you cannot connect to yarn. What is the yarn cluster configuration?

Comment: Sorry Im just starting to learn Spark, how can I see the yarn cluster configuration?

Comment: I guess you did not install the hadoop cluster, so there is no yarn environment. In this case, you cannot use spark on yarn mode.

Comment: Ah I see thanks! How can I install the hadoop cluster?

Comment: This is a more complicated topic. If you want to manually build a hadoop cluster from scratch, you can refer to its official documentation: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/ClusterSetup.html

Comment: Thanks you for the help! Really appreciated